# Variable in array and value separed with comma

Tags: php

My code is:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
{
  $resultstr[] = "FIND_IN_SET (" .$value. ", Dotazioni) > 0";   
}
$dotazioni_camera = implode(" and ",$resultstr);
echo($dotazioni_camera);
```

Result is:

```
FIND_IN_SET (1, Dotazioni) > 0 and FIND_IN_SET (2, Dotazioni) > 0 and FIND_IN_SET (3, Dotazioni) > 0
```

This is correct!!
But if i try to change Arr from

```
 $arr = array(1,2,3);
```

To

```
 $arr = array($var);
```

the result change in:

```
FIND_IN_SET (1,2,3, Dotazioni) > 0
```

I think that variable convert integer value separeted by comma in a string value.
I looked for a possible solution but I did not find anything.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: what does $var has ?

Comment: can you please share your $var value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
$var = '1,2,3';
```

When you call

```
$arr = array($var);
```

This is an array of 1 value - `1,2,3`.  If you want to have an array of values 1, 2 and 3, you will have to do something like...

```
$var = '1,2,3';
$arr = explode(",", $var);
```